# return view after ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

after an async call with jquery how can I return a particolar view?

this my caller view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Run() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: "/Home/Run",
            data: $("#form_run").serializeArray(),
            dataType: "json"
        });

    }

</script>
<form action="javascript:return true;" method="post" id="form_run">
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" />
    <input type="text" id="cognome" name="cognome" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Run" onclick="Run();" />
</form>
```

this my controller action:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Run(string nome, string cognome)
    {
        return View("Result");
    }
```

can not display view "Result"
How?

Comment: That defeats the purpose of AJAX.

Answer (score 7):

You can not return a `View` from an asynchronous call.
An ajax request is meant to avoid doing an entire page cycle.

You should just do a `POST` back if you want a new `View` to be returned.

The other option would to be have a callback upon success of the ajax call and set the `window.location` to the new `View` so the page does a `GET` to the new `View`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a call back function that will redirect the user once the AJAX returned.

```
ajax(/*suff*/).success(callbackFuntion);
```

And then in your callback

```
function callbackFuntion(){

    window.location = "www.google.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In common `ASP.NET MVC` worklfow a view is associated to a controller. So if you want to change a view, to render a different `HTML` content in the browser, based on `AJAX` request, just make in a way that *url* of that request is routed to another `controller`. Form *that* controller return a new `View(...)`.

Can have a look on  [ASP.NET MVC Views Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs)

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.